# How to background a div without the padding area

Tags: html, css

I have this class on CSS :

```
.mgmtError{ 
  width:716px; 
  float:left; 
  background-color:#FF0000; 
  padding:10px; 
  text-align:center;
}
```

and I'd like to color the background not in the padding area. 
I tryed with margin, but seems that it have some troubles with IE.

Any others solution?

Comment: Could you show your HTML markup?

Comment: The padding area is part of the DIV so you can't say "have background A in part of the DIV and background B in other part of same DIV".

Comment: What are the problems with IE when using margin?

Comment: @DanielB : sometimes, if there isn't a next float element, margin-bottom will fail; I think it's a common problem...

Comment: I guess you could use a div in a div .. to simulate the padding, with the larger div not having a color

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are able to access the HTML try:

```css
.mgmtError {
  width: 716px;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: blue;
}

.mgmtError div {
  background-color: #FF0000;
}
```

```html
<div class="mgmtError">
  <div>Content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Answer from @Yacine below seems better.

Answer (score 453):

You can use

```css
background-clip: content-box;
```

Also make sure to use `background-color` property, not `background`.

Comment: This is css3 and will not work on IE before 9.0, why cant you use margin instead of padding?

Comment: It's a nice solution. But when you use `background-image: linear-gradient()` you cannot use percentage color stops. As I think about it it's kind of obvious, because it's content*clipping* but I tried for some time

Comment: And I found a solution with `background-origin: content-box`

Comment: I don't understand, everybody says "Brilliant" and more than 200 +1 but this doesn't work for me. Any ideas? The padding and the background appear in the same color

Comment: @GilEpshtain Can you provide an MCVE via e.g. jsfiddle? Your comment isn't much use otherwise.

Comment: @GilEpshtain, make sure to use `background-color`, not `background`.

Comment: This did the trick for me! For more notes, this should be placed after the background property