# Bootstrap 3: Missing gutters

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Just started playing around with bootstrap 3 and I can't get gutters between columns to work.

I created the most basic code to test with:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0-rc1/js/bootstrap.min.js">                                                                                                                                  </script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0-rc1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
    <style>
        .box1 {
            background-color: green;
        }
        .box2 {
            background-color: blue;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 box1">
            <h1>Test</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-8 box2">
            <h1>Test2</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</html>
```

And the result is just one big green/blue box without any gutter in between the two columns.
I have also tried it on a fiddle with no luck http://jsfiddle.net/Tgkkb/
What am I missing?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Bootstrap 3 switched to using `padding` for the gutters rather than `margin`s. So, the content is parted, but the boxes aren't. And a `background-color` will fill the `padding` as well.

Though, you should be able to get the desired effect by setting the background on inner boxes:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="box1">
            <h1>Test</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <div class="box2">
            <h1>Test2</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PFxUk/

---

Though, the goal is just to apply the `background` [to a single, wrapping child](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5896603). So, if the headers definitely won't have any siblings, then you can possibly forgo the additional `<div>`s:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <h1 class="box1">Test</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <h1 class="box2">Test2</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/G2gbG/

Comment: You are a life saver...as a fairly experienced developer, I had been frustrated by this for hours...ugh..Any chance you know where it goes over this in the docs? They seem to be pretty bad so far.  Thanks again.

Comment: @bcoop713 I haven't seen a mention of the change in the docs for 3.0 -- they're kind of written with a "*forget about Bootstrap 2*" tone. But, it is mentioned in the [Bootstrap 3 Pull Request](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/6342) (linked in the [release announcement](http://blog.getbootstrap.com/2013/07/27/bootstrap-3-rc1/)) under "Grid System" with the "New single grid system."

Comment: @JonathanLonowski - this answer it spot on, hence my upvote, but do you know of a way of removing these additional divs (box1 etc.) whilst still allow the gutters to appear? I have a list of li's that have col-sm-2 etc so your solution would imply I include additional divs inside these li's, but it would mean shifting everything about and would massively interfere with existing jQuery and CSS.

Comment: @DeeMac I added an alternate example that may help. But, if the `<li>`s have a single child already, such as an `<a>` wrapping other content, you can apply the `background` to it (may need `display: block` or `display: inline-block`). Otherwise, if [IE9+ support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip#Browser_compatibility) is sufficient, you can apply the `background` with [`background-clip: content-box`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13399086) to the `<li>`s.

Comment: I really dislike in this solution that the typography goes against the edge. In other words, it does a lot more then creating a gutter. Is there any way around that?

Comment: This was sooooo frustrating! Thanks for this answer! Seems like a major change in behavior that should have been documented more (also, ugh...back to adding 'inner divs' to everything again. Sigh.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the padding or margin for your columns, you can use the `row-no-gutters` class on the row (introduced in v3.4.0) and add your own padding and background.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/#grid-remove-gutters