# Adding horizontal spacing between divs in Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid

I want to include a small horizontal space between the "Away Team" and "Baseball Field" divs, as presented in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VmejS/. I have tried altering padding, margins, including decimal column offsets, all unsuccessfully.

Here is the html:

```
 <body>
    <div class='container'>
      <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-md-12 panel' id='gameplay-title'>Title</div>
      </div>
      <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 panel' id='gameplay-scoreboard'>Scoreboard</div>
      </div>
      <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-md-3 panel' id='gameplay-away-team'>Away Team</div>
        <div class='col-md-6 panel' id='gameplay-baseball-field'>Baseball Field</div>
        <div class='col-md-3 panel' id='gameplay-home-team'>Home Team</div>
      </div>
      <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 panel' id='gameplay-at-bat'>At Bat</div>
      </div>
      <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 panel' id='gameplay-game-report'>Game Report</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: Hey Steve, why would you want a horizontal space between vertically stacked items? Not sure I follow here. Do you want these two items specifically to be inline, and with a space?

Comment: I found my answer here.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18071055/bootstrap-3-missing-gutters

Comment: Why are you using `'` over `"`?

Comment: did anyone figure out what was meant by 'small horizontal space between' stacked items? I'm really curious!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The best solution is not to use the same element for column and panel:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="panel" id="gameplay-away-team">Away Team</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="panel" id="gameplay-baseball-field">Baseball Field</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="panel" id="gameplay-home-team">Home Team</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and some more styles:

```
#gameplay-baseball-field {
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this make the middle div thinner than the rest giving a uneven aspect?

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like this?
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/VmejS/1/)

Attribute used:

```
margin-left: 50px;
```

Comment: I still want the divs to be in the same row. Adding margin pushes the last div into a position I don't want it to be in.

Comment: Well, you didn't really express that. I assumed you might want to make a navigation-like-thing because that was the closest approximation of "a horizontal space between them" - my first thought was "why would you want a empty line between those two with some spaces"

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand you want to make a navigation bar or something similar to it. What I recommend doing is making a list and editing the items from there.
Just try this;

```
<ul>
    <li class='item col-md-12 panel' id='gameplay-title'>Title</li>
    <li class='item col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 panel' id='gameplay-scoreboard'>Scoreboard</li>
</ul>
```

And so on... To add more categories add another ul in there. Now, for the CSS you just need this;

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
}
.item {
    display: inline;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
```

Comment: <ul class="list-inline"> helps with this.