# No gutter spacing in Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've added some basic code to my document but there isn't any gutter spacing between each section like there would be on a 960 grid layout

if there something that i might be missing here?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-4 block">
        hello this is a test block
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 block">
        hello this is a test block
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 block">
        hello this is a test block
    </div>
</div>

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.block{
    background-color:#6CC;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap 3: Missing gutters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18071055/bootstrap-3-missing-gutters)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Bootstrap 3, the gutter is created using padding (instead of margins) so your `block` needs to be inside the `col-*`

Demo: http://bootply.com/109679

---

Bootstrap 4: [How to remove gutter space for a specific div only - bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16489307/how-to-remove-gutter-space-for-a-specific-div-only-bootstrap/21282059#21282059)