# Bootstrap 3 box based layout padding without effecting gutter

Tags: css, layout, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid, gutter

I'm making a box based layout and I'm having issues with the gutters in bootstrap 3. Since they've been changed to be padded since bootstrap 2, every time I want to add padding to a box it completely destroys the gutter. I can't seem to find a way of remedying the problem.

I use a .box class to highlight the box from it's gutter and give them background colours and images. I want padding inside the box for the text so it's not right on the edge of the box walls, so I made a .box-inner class, but I can't just apply padding to it :/

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="box">
                <div class="box-inner">
                    <h1>Test2</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be very appreciated! I've been banging my head against the wall for hours.

Fiddle here, I highlighted the problem areas with a comment:
http://jsfiddle.net/kbj8dd0e/6/

Comment: What's wrong with the padding of box-inner? They seem to do their natural function.

Comment: Nevermind, see whats happening there...

Comment: I'm not sure if it's as obvious in that example, I'll try and make it fit the screen better. But basically where the red boxes are in this updated fiddle, the padding destroys the 30px gutter and I want the padding to be contained within it's box and not interfere with the gutter in any way:

http://jsfiddle.net/kbj8dd0e/6/

Comment: It seems that Bootstrap's col-md-6 size isn't loading.

Comment: I should go to bed, posting total stupid comments sorry bro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can add padding. Just add it to the `.box`.

Have a look at this:
http://jsfiddle.net/kbj8dd0e/5/
*(note that I changed the `col-md` to `col-xs` to make it show better in that small fiddle pane, but the same should work for any `col` class.)*

All I did was move the padding to the `.box` class to be able to remove the redundant `.box-inner`. I also removed all your instances of `<div class="row"><div class="col-md-12">...</div></div>` as this just adds markup and serves no purpose whatsoever.

Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Unfortunately your edit makes the gutters uneven, which is what I'm trying to avoid. They need to remain the same width of 30px on top, bottom, left and right, but allow a padding inside of the box, the .box class is being used to show the gutters, so I made a box-inner class to add padding within the box, but it actually makes the box bigger rather than keeping it the same size. I'll try and link you to a question that'll help you understand my reasoning for the box class better:

EDIT, here's the link :)!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18071055/bootstrap-3-missing-gutters

Comment: If you want the bottom margin to be 30px, then just make it 30px... http://jsfiddle.net/kbj8dd0e/7/ Still don't really get the problem I think?

Comment: I added the link above for you :)!

Comment: OH that did it! Sorry about the lack of understanding, I've had a pretty long day doing some intense problem solving and I'm still a bit of a newbie. Getting there but I have my random moments. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thanks so much man, I've been working out how to do this all day because I've not seen a design laid out in such a boxed and customised way before, wrote an overly complex framework to make the boxes, realised it was overly complex and scrapped it, tried some custom grids that weren't powerful enough, FINALLY got somewhere but couldn't add padding. Oh man, and the solution ended up being so elegant. Absolutely perfect. Take care x

Comment: No problem, glad I could be of assistance.