# Why is the padding between the bootstrap columns getting lost

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am pretty new to bootstrap and have been beating my head up with the following problem. Whenever I use the following code, the padding between the columns is getting lost.

```
<body>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4 col"></div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col"></div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body><!--end body-->
```

But whenever I move the class col inside the column, then the code works exactly as expected.

```
<body>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="col"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="col"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="col"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body><!--end body-->
```

Following is the CSS class that I am using

```
<style>
            .col{
                min-height: 500px;
                background-color: gray;
            }
</style>
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle please?

Comment: What version of Bootstrap?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gv034bgL/5/
Above is the fiddle link for the same. @RehbanKhatri

Comment: @ZimSystem bootstrap 3.3.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap does not add space *between* the columns, it adds space *inside* each column. So if you put another div inside each column that will give the space you want.

The way I look at it is the columns only act as containers for the actual content, which goes inside them.

jsfiddle of the kind of thing I think you should do instead: https://jsfiddle.net/bqadptzL/

CSS:

```
.col {
  /* just to demonstrate */
  background-color: red;      
}

.box {
  background-color:gray;
  min-height: 500px;         
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
      <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-4 col">
                <div class="box">
                  Content
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-4 col">
                <div class="box">
                  Content
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-4 col">
                <div class="box">
                  Content
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
</body><!--end body-->
```

If you look at the grid system examples, you will see there is no space between the columns, only inside them. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Hope that helps.

Sidenote: you should not put columns inside columns, **you should only put columns inside rows**. But you can put rows inside columns. So you can alternate row - column - row - column, not row - column - column. This is how Bootstrap system is meant to work.

Comment: Thanks, this was really helpful

Comment: @RushilAhuja That's ok, please check the sidenote I just added too, which I think might also help.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the second version you get a margin created by the div you added,
if you add a margin to the .col css class you should see the difference.
[You can take a look here for a more detailed answer about how to work with the columns in bootstrap with a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18071055/bootstrap-3-missing-gutters)

Comment: Bootstrap columns don't have margins, they have padding.

Answer (score 0):

**The padding is not getting lost.** In Bootstrap, `col-sm-*` has 15px padding. Remember, the background color fills *entire* the width of the cell, padding included.

You're putting the bg color on the column with padding, and in the other case it's on the inner column that doesn't have padding.

Put the background-color and a border, *only* on the `col-sm-4`. and you'll see the difference. The padding is there, and the same in both cases...

http://www.codeply.com/go/lf2V9vlIsr